# snapshot.childrenCount me retorna el número de hijos pero me arroja la misma cantidad de variables que el número de hijos

Tags: firebase, swift, xcode

Necesito saber el número de hijos que tiene mi Database, sin embargo cuando hago snapshot.childrenCount me arroja el número de hijos pero también me arroja la misma cantidad de variables dependiendo del número de hijos que tenga. Es enredado, aquí un ejemplo:

Si mi snapshot.childrenCount tiene 4 hijos, me arroja lo siguiente:

```
4

4

4

4
```

Si mi snapshot.childrenCount tiene 2 hijos, me arroja lo siguiente:

```
2

2
```

Este es el código:

```
            self.ref.child(self.Tipo1)
                .queryOrdered(byChild: "tipo").queryEqual(toValue: "Sí")
                .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                        let tipo1 = snapshot.childrenCount
                        self.txttipo1.text = "\(tipo1)"
}
                            })
```

Sólo necesito que me arroje un valor de esos, no que me entregue la misma cantidad de variables que el número de hijos...

Alguien sabe por qué ocurre eso?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Necesitas conocer todos los hijos del Database o de una referencia ? Tenes el codigo ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén Necesito saber sólo el número de hijos que tiene, es decir que si tiene 4 que me diga sólo un valor con el número 4, no que me arroje una cadena de números...

Comment: podrias poner la estructura de tu base de datos y la referencia que usas para leer esos hijos ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén Creo que es el FOR que estoy usando... No me había fijado en eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en el for, `childrenCount` te devuelve la cantidad de hijos de una referencia (nodo) en particular, si usas un for, vas a repetir la accion la misma cantidad de veces cuantos hijos encuentres con `snapshot.children`

La solucion es quitar el for y solo usar

```
let tipo1 = snapshot.childrenCount
```